# The side box/blurb to the right of the screen irritating while editing

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Are these two boxes meant to move with the scrolling motion? If I scroll down to the bottom of the page to check out other stackexchange pages I can check out, this beige box follows me around, blocking the right most links.

Is this something that just happens to me? Or in every browser?

Kinda seems to hint that unless I'm done editing whatever I've been typing, I'm not supposed to use the bottom right links.

I've added a screenshot of the bug. And yes, it's on another stackexchange site, but it's the same everywhere? Is it really a bug?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Adding a screenshot would help us understand what you mean.

Comment: The yellow "how to edit" boxes stay in place while the page scrolls, and they cover the footer if you scroll to the bottom of the page. That might be what he's talking about, or maybe there are some related links below the boxes that are getting covered.

Comment: In Chrome, the help boxes stay in the same spot, while the page scrolls on behind them. At least for me. Is it something to with my own browser settings?

Comment: I think the help boxes stay in the same spot for everybody. Rand al'Thor has your answer, if I understand the question correctly.

Comment: Wow. How do we do THAT? The screenshot thingy? @Rand al'Thor

Comment: There's a little icon that looks like a mountain, which you can click on while editing to insert an image into your post; Ctrl+G also works. You can either upload images from your computer or take them from elsewhere on the web.

Answer (score 2):

<sub>I *think* you're talking about the "How to Edit" / "How to Format" boxes in the right sidebar which appear when you're asking</sub> <sup>or editing a question. If I've misinerpreted your question, I'll delete this answer.</sup>

**This is by design, and isn't going to be changed.**

The same issue has been raised on main meta: [Right-hand sidebar covers the footer on the "ask question" page and markdown help page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/136849/right-hand-sidebar-covers-the-footer-on-the-ask-question-page-and-markdown-hel). The answer posted there by Pops, a Community Manager employed by Stack Exchange, says:

> We think that sidebar is pretty important, and want it to remain visible. The footer, on the other hand, isn't *that* important, and can always be accessed again with a bit of scrolling up. It's not worth the time to tweak the page so that it's only scrollable until the point of overlap.

Answer (score -1):

I see no such behaviour in my device (Android 4/5?).

[image: gif of screen scrolling on mibile]

Tell us your device, it might help

Comment: Try it on a site where you don't have enough rep to edit posts in-line. I get the same effect on M&TV, for instance.

Comment: @Randal'Thor The "how to edit" boxes stop moving if you have edit privileges? Quick, somebody upvote me 6 times so I can see it.

Comment: @anaranjada Ohhh, you're the user formerly known as amarillo! I've seen you around a bit with this name but didn't realise it was you.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Yes, I briefly mentioned it in chat but I changed names without fanfare. Being an orange candle (grammatically feminine) and having the masculine adjective for "yellow" as a name, I felt like I was living a lie.

Comment: I was actually using it on Chrome. On my computer.

Comment: @SphoorthyNutulapatithis this is Chrome on desk to mode. I was mainly hoping this would spur you into taking us your browser and whether you were in mobile or not.

Comment: Huh, now that I have 2k rep, I can edit posts inline, and the "how to edit" boxes are gone. My mind is blown. @Randal'Thor

Comment: @anaranjada Congrats, and enjoy your new editing powers! :-)

Comment: Woah. I have to wait for another 1,884 increase in rep for that to like, go away?

Comment: @SphoorthyNutulapati You could use your own style sheet to make the boxes disappear. Or maybe you could set AdBlock to block the boxes. So you'd either need to figure out how to make your browser remove them, or you need a lot more rep, yes.

Comment: A style sheet? Could you explain that? Or I could just ask it on the meta page

Comment: @SphoorthyNutulapati Well... it's possible to edit the page however you like, in theory, but you either have to learn how to do it or find somebody else who's already done it. I guess it depends on how much the boxes bug you.